# Как получить номер элемента в списке?

Tags: python, list, список

```
abc = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
j = 'b'
if j in abc:
    # нужно сделать чтобы j стал равен 'd'
```

Что нужно сделать, чтобы получить номер b в списке и изменить его?

Answer (score 2):

Для этого существует метод [list.index](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
abc = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
j = 'b'
j_idx = abc.index(j)
print(j_idx)
# 1
```